# How to get value from kendo combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox, kendo-ui

How can I get from  kendo combobox value? I always getting undefined on it.. I've used these variants, but they are not worked for me

```
var selected = $('#typesCombo').data('kendoComboBox').val();
var selected = $('#typesCombo').data('kendoComboBox').value();
var selected = $('#typesCombo').data('kendoComboBox');
```

And getting error like: `Cannot read property 'val' of undefined`

Here's my code:

JS:

```
$('#loadContainer').load("@Url.Action("Load", "Home")" + id);

var selected = $('#typesCombo').data('kendoComboBox').val();

if (selected == '') {
    ...
    }
```

HTML:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(x => x.Types.Name).Name("typesCombo")
                                             .DataTextField("Name")
                                             .DataValueField("Id")
                                             .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%", id = "typesCombo" })
                                             .BindTo(Model.TypesList))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many ways to get the widget selected value. If you are trying to get the value after it initialization **and** it has no selected value(declared in the [`index`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#configuration-index) parameter) you will get an empty value. If you want to get the value when user changes it, you can use the [`select`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#events-select) event and get the value like this:

```
$("#typesCombo").data('kendoComboBox').value(); // The selected value itself
$("#typesCombo").data('kendoComboBox').dataItem(); // The selected entire dataItem object
$("#typesCombo").val(); // Only if the target element is an input element
```

[Working demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ECoPa)

Answer (score 11):

You forget use # before id.
Try following:

```
var selected = $("#typesCombo").data('kendoComboBox').value()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var object= $("#typesCombo").data('kendoComboBox').dataItem() // For getting the selected object
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this fixes the problem? What does it do that the things the OP tried already doesn't?